# UILabel has wrong frame. Swift

Tags: swift, uilabel, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I added four UILabels inside a cell and it seems that I added all the necessary constraints but I cannot make my labels to have a frame that is equal to its text content. Also setting a height is not an option. The label looks like this (text appears in the center and the frame is big):

[image]

And I want it to have like this:

[image]

Also, I'm doing everything programmatically so I'm not looking for solution using Interface Builder

Comment: could it be the font size?

Comment: Do show the code that you've tried so far for us to help you

Comment: Sharing what you've done so far would help. There are simply too many things that could be causing this. We would need to see your code in order to narrow down a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the label to be the size of the content, set the *Content Hugging Priority* to `.required`:

```
label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
```

This will prevent lower priority constraints from stretching your label.

Answer (score 0):

```
label.font = label.font.withSize(label.frame.height)
```